# Which way of fetching is more Efficient in Redis?

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

Hi I'm fairly new to [Redis](http://redis.io/) and Currently face a problem. My problem is "*I don't know which way is better performance*"

**Way#1** : Cache All data to Redis and then Query to it ( I don't know is it possible to Query to Redis ? if possible How ? )

for example in following table cache all data to single Key ( By this way in my table we have 1 key ) and then Query for users with same City.

**Way#2** : Cache all users with same City in separate Key ( By this way in my table we have 4 key ) and then Fetch each Key separately.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache all users with same City in separate Key - the Redis way. Fast insert, fast get in cost of much memory consumption or some data redundancy.

In general you can't follow your `way#1` example. Why not? Redis do not have any in box solutions for query data in sql terms. You can't do something like `select something from somethere where criteria` in most of Redis data structures. You can write LUA script for complex map/redus solutioin on your data - but not in out of box.

You should remeber, each time you want to say `Join this and this data` you should understand - you can do this only in client application space or in redis LUA script. Yes, you have some types in `join` capacity with ZSET and SET's but it not that you require.